Resolving Touchscreen and Tablet Mode Issues on a Laptop Running Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS
My laptop's touchscreen isn't working as expected—it can be laggy at times. Additionally, the keyboard remains active while in tablet mode, which hinders normal usage.
I found some information online suggesting that it's possible to add event listeners to disable the keyboard and touchpad whenever tablet mode is activated. However, I'm also facing issues with inconsistent touchscreen interactions with the OS interface. What is the best way to fix it?
